# Which client library to use to interact with Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-compute-api

I am working on a project to interact with Google Cloud Compute. For that I found 2 ways to interact with Google Cloud using Python (Can use other languages too);

Google API clients(Rest orchestration) -  **google-api-python-client**

Google cloud clients  -  For compute - **google-cloud-compute**

Now Google api client works for me but since it is not the recommended way, I tried to evaluate Google Cloud clients. For that I checked google-cloud-compute but it is in aplha stage with no GA timelines mentioned.

I checked nodejs, golang, and python compute clients too but google compute client libraries are all in either preview or alpha.

So, should I carry on with Google API Client libraries or wait for compute clients to mature enough.

Comment: It's funny because yesterday I attended a presentation session of these libraries (session performed by Googlers to GDE community). They are still working on them, especially on the default value part. The advantage is a more idiomatic development and a full GRPC support. But yes, still in progresse even if very close to the final release. no ETA also on our side, but you can expect a GA in Q3 I think. In any cases, the Google CLoud client libraries are the future. Use them for all your new developments.

Comment: The Cloud (!) Client Libraries are only available for GCP services. If you're using Google's non-Cloud services (Ads, Docs, Maps etc.), these are only available as API Client Libraries. So, while the Cloud Client Libraries are idiomatic and preferred for Cloud development, if you're using more of a smorgasbord, you'll likely end up using both flavors of SDK (and you may prefer to standardize on API).See here for an explanation of the different flavors: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained

Comment: Also, the Cloud Client libraries haven't been (this may have changed) auto-generated from discovery documents and so, while API Clients are *always* current, Cloud Clients can lag the service.

Comment: Thankyou. I am mostly interested with gcloud compute. I am anyways inclined towards the client libraries and [https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute/issues/53](https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute/issues/53) got my hopes up. Probably i will wait atleast google compute client lib is in beta atleast.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the client libraries team for GCP. Per the [ref docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_cloud_client_libraries) we have a suite of new libraries recently published in preview. While we can't yet guarantee backward compatibility we are actively working on stabilizing the surface. So they're not yet suitable for production but if you are in research/feasibility stage then we encourage you to explore `google-cloud-compute` over `google-api-python-client`. We would welcome your feedback!

Aside, we have also made significant improvements, and continue to invest in automating the update and release of libraries so that the most current API surface is available in Python and all the languages we support.